# Running a particular XML file for a chosen test suite (TestNG, Surefire)

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm playing around this plugin and I wanted to run in terminal a specific test suite by its `xml` file.

when I do:

`"mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile="test123Suite.xml"`

it would always begin running the *testng* `xml` suite. When I switch their order in `suiteXMLFiles`, the first `xml` will trigger after the command even though i specified the name.

Why is `surefire` ignoring the fact that I don't want to run both of these suites and only runs them in order?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <reportsDirectory>target/surefire-reports-${surefire.forkNumber}</reportsDirectory>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>test123Suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <parallel>suites</parallel>
        <threadCountSuites>2</threadCountSuites>
        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have also put fork count to *1* so it doesnt run both of them at the same time, but what it probably does is runs both of them but sequentially.

I just wanted to call:

`mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile="test123Suite.xml"`

and run only tests inside of that suite.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define the whole set of suite files you need to use property **`surefire.suiteXmlFiles`**, not `surefire.suiteXmlFile`.

this will run both

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="test123Suite.xml,testng.xml"
```

this will run only one

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="testng.xml"
```

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="test123Suite.xml"
```